# Was Rebel Without a Cause shot in color?

Tags: rebel-without-a-cause

I’ve read somewhere that Rebel Without a Cause was actually shot in color, not black and white, but couldn’t believe it since the colors in it wasn’t too real! So was what I saw (colors) is real straight from the camera or it was just colorized years after the film?

Answer (score 8):

### Yes.

*Rebel Without a Cause* was filmed in color. Interestingly, they started shooting it in black and white, but then switched to color because Jack Warner (president of Warner Brothers studios) believed that James Dean was a rising star and merited a color movie. They had to reshoot numerous scenes that were first filmed in black and white. [Source.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebel_Without_a_Cause)

If the color doesn't look real to you, it's probably because it was an early color film and the early color film didn't look as natural as later color film would.

Comment: What about east of eden?

Comment: East of Eden was also filmed in color. I know early color looks a little off, but have you seen an actual colorized BW movie? They look horrible.

Comment: Oh I dunno, I like the way Holiday Inn turned out.

Comment: YMMV - To be honest I haven't even looked at a colorized movie since Turner first attempted it. I'm sure the technique improved.

Comment: @Banana 1416: is there something holding you back from accepting my answer? I feel like I gave you a definitive, sourced answer to your question.